# Краш приложения на IOS

Tags: swift, xcode

Всем добрый день. Возникла такая проблема, когда телефон подключён к маку, и я запускаю приложения в Xcode, приложение на телефоне нормально работает, стоит только отключить телефон от ноутбука и запустить снова приложение, оно запускается но при нажатии на любую кнопку тут же вылетает. Точно такая-же проблема на заведомо рабочем приложении которое работало. Единственно что сделал это обновил систему на телефоне

Comment: у меня такое иногда бывает. Попробуй перезагрузить телефон. Выключить и включить.

Comment: Пробовал не помогло, еще есть предположение что кабель для телефона не оригинальный. Попробую на днях кабель другой найти

Comment: Что за приложение у вас? Какой функционал в нем реализован? 
Подобная проблема описана тут: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1181622/ios-приложение-с-картой-mkmapview-вылетает-при-запуске и была решена подключением недостающего модуля.