# iOS-приложение с картой (MKMapView) вылетает при запуске

Tags: swift, карты, геолокация

На один из View Controller iOS-приложения был добавлен MKMapView, который показывает карту Apple.

Если запустить через xCode на устройстве, то все нормально работает, а если запустить просто в телефоне, то приложение падает при переходе на View Controller c картой.
Соответственно, никаких логов не отображается.

В plist строчка для доступа к службам геолокации добавлена.

**Похожие вопросы** (не помогли решить проблему):

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7269303/mkmapview-crashes-app-when-view-controller-popped

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40366485/swift-mkmapview-sometimes-becomes-nil-and-app-crashes

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46876509/app-crashes-strangely-regarding-mkmapview-memory-issues

Comment: Что еще помимо добавленной карты в Вашем контроллере?

Comment: Вообще ничего. Добавлял 2 label, потом убрал, проблема не в них. Если карту убрать, то все нормально работает - не вылетает (у View Controller там имеется дополнительная логика, без визуализации)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Аналогичная проблема недавно была решена с помощью добавления Map KIT в проект xCode: выделить приложение в TARGETS, открыть вкладку "Signing and Capabilities", нажать на кнопку "+ Capability" и в открывшемся окне найти MAPS и перетащить его в xCode.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если Map KIT уже добавлен, то уже сложнее...

Comment: Точно, Map Kit не был подключен! Спасибо.